# Get latitude longitude from a jxmapviewer2

Tags: java, swing, openstreetmap, jxmapviewer

I'm displaying an OSM map with the library [jxmapviewer2](https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2).

I cannot manage to get the lat lon of a point of the map, for istance I would like to get the geographic coordinates of a spot by clicking it

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
  if(e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
    java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
    double X = p.getX();
    double Y = p.getY();
    System.out.println("X:"+X+",Y:"+Y);
  }
}
```

This code above returns an output like:

```
X:239.0,Y:113.0
```

Comment: What component have you added the mouse listener too? Most likely you have to use `public GeoPosition convertPointToGeoPosition(Point2D pt)` that is part of the class `JXMapViewer`.

Comment: It worked, Thank you!

Comment: You should consider marking the actual answer as correct then, if that is what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have created a `JXMapViewer` and added your mouse listener to that, then you can use your viewer to get the GeoPosition.

```
JXMapViewer viewer;
//initialize somehow.
viewer.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.getClickCount() == 1 && e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3){
                java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
                GeoPosition geo = viewer.convertPointToGeoPosition(p);
                System.out.println("X:"+geo.getLattitude()+",Y:"+geo.getLongitude());
            }
     }
});
```